# DOM with XPath in Android 2.1

Tags: android, xml, dom, xpath

Are there any good/stable 3rd party XML DOM parsers (with XPath support) which work with Android 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is default support for [XPath in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) starting in API level 8, which is 2.2.

If you have no particular need to work with 2.1, that should be just fine.  If working with 2.1 is a necessity, I would recommend using a [SAX parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) or a [StAX (pull) parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), both of which have been around since API level 1.

Comment: Thank you, but I was specifically looking for a DOM parser, and preferably one with XPath support. Also, I am stuck with using API level 7. Which is why I was asking for 3rd party parsers.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the [included Document Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) available since API v1? Though if you are just looking to parse XML style documents then I would recommend the [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I cannot use the default DOM parser of API level 7 because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017559/android-dom-parsing-with-entities-in-tags

Comment: @sparkymat: Then just try and use Simple instead.