# Getting "&lt;" instead of "<" from SOAP response breaks on one device, but not another

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, ascii

I am sending a SOAP POST that returns some xml.  I've been testing on a newer device (Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1) and it's been working fine. However, I just tried running it on an older device (HTC Desire HD running Android 2.2), and I am getting a `ParseException: At line 1, column 0: unclosed token`.  Here is the relevant code:

```
String xml = null;
Document doc = null;
String SOAPRequest = "[SOAP REQUEST HERE]";          

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("[WEBSITE HERE]");
InputStream soapResponse = null;
try {
    StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(SOAPRequest, HTTP.UTF_8);
    postEntity.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(postEntity);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

    // Convert HttpResponse to InputStream
    HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    soapResponse = responseEntity.getContent();
    //// printing response here gives me ...<Result>&lt;blahblahblah&gt;<Result>...

    // Get the SearchResult xml
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = db.parse(soapResponse);

} catch ...

NodeList soapNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Result");
xml = soapNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

//// printing xml here gives me "<" 
return xml;
```

Taking a look at the httpResponse, the part that I am interested in looks like this: `<Result>&lt;blahblahblah&gt;</Result>`.

When I try to get this `xml` using the `NodeList`, `&lt;blahblahblah&gl;` turns into just the character `<`.

Why is this a problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be relevant:

[android DOM parsing with entities in tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017559/android-dom-parsing-with-entities-in-tags)

...which leads to this:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2607

...which seems to indicate that on earlier Android versions the DOM parser doesn't deal with entity references properly. The bug report there discusses something about how entities are treated as a separate child rather than merged into the adjacent text node(s) which sounds oddly like your situation.

If this is the problem you're having then try switching to using the SAX parser. It's (IMHO) just such an easier XML parser to deal with as well.

Comment: Thank you! I will switch to SAX parser. I looked into SAX vs DOM a bit and decided on DOM just because it seemed like I would have to make another class for the SAX parser, and I was lazy... But is it something I could also inline? Just curious.

Comment: I personally really like using the SAX parser. At first it may seem a pain to use considering you get all your start tags, character data, end tags, etc. via callbacks and you also have to maintain a bit of state yourself. But I find it so much nicer than having to deal with walking a DOM and deal with nodelists, etc. I would say that a DOM parser is probably only justified if it's a complex XML document and / or you kind of need random access to it.

Comment: Example of SAX use is this SVG parser I wrote (still a bit messy): https://github.com/TrevorPage/TPSVG_Android_SVG_Library/blob/master/TPSVG/src/com/trevorpage/tpsvg/Tpsvg.java  The SAX parser is set up in the few lines that begin `SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()...` and the necessary callbacks are `endElement()`, `startDocument()`, `startElement()`, `characters()`.

Comment: For the record, that fixed it. And it was pretty painless :)